# WPF Stop BackgroundWorker from main thread

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading

i have a BackgroundWorker that execute work in the background. the work is run some .exe application in command prompt and wait for output for display. sometimes the .exe app is stack or takes a lot of time. i want to stop the worker after one minute in case it is still running.
the issue is that i have a progress bar  that runs in the main thread for 1 minute. i want to stop the worker when the progress bar is full (after 1 minute) **from the main thread (UI)**. here is my code:

```
    private void btnTest_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        wTest = new BackgroundWorker();
        wTest .DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(wTest _DoWork);
        wTest .RunWorkerCompleted += wTest _RunWorkerCompleted;
        wTest .WorkerReportsProgress = true;
        wTest .WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
        wTest .RunWorkerAsync();

        while (pbTest.Value < 91)
        {               
            if (!wTest.CancellationPending)
            {
                pbTest.Value = (pbTest.Value + 100/60);
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
            }
            Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Background,
                                       new ThreadStart(delegate { }));
        }
    }

    void wTest_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        //call .exe application and wait for output
    }
```

how can i do it?

Comment: stop the background worker or stop the process it started?

Comment: i want to stop the worker. i can asume it will stop the process too?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using .net 4.5, you can use the `Task` class and the associated `CancellationTokeSource` and `CancellationToken` classes. Note that tasks support reporting progress through the `IProgress` interface. Stephen Cleary has a good [example](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/reporting-progress-from-async-tasks.html) on this.

If the work you were doing does not provide an asynchronous interface you can use `Task.Run` to execute it and pass a `CancellationToken` to monitor for cancellation. As you are doing the work you need to monitor the token for cancellation. One way to do this is to call [ThrowIfCancellationRequested](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.cancellationtoken.throwifcancellationrequested%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) which will throw a `OperationCancelledException` if `Cancel` has been called on the `CancellationTokenSource`. `CancellationTokenSource` also supports cancellation after a certain time, which will be handy for your scenario.

```
private CancellationTokenSource cts;

private void btnTest_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if(cts == null)
    {
        cts = new CancellationTokenSource(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 60)); // cancel after 60 seconds
    }

    await Task.Run( () => Work(), cts.Token);

    cts = null;
}

void Work(CancellationToken token)
{
   // do work
  token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
  // do work
}
```

Comment: i am using .NET 3.5. this class is included in .NET 4

Comment: Ok, I'll mention that my answer is for .net 4.5

Comment: is there any way to do it for .net 3.5?

Comment: Not with `async` and `await`, but if you wanted to use the Task Parallel Library you can try this port for .net 3.5 http://www.nuget.org/packages/TaskParallelLibrary. But if you can, it is better to upgrade to .net 4.0 or 4.5. That gives you a lot more options

Answer (score 1):

You will need to do two things to enable work cancellation of your `BackgroundWorker`. First, you will need to check for the [`BackgroundWorker.CancellationPending` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.cancellationpending.aspx) in your `DoWork` handler method:

```
private void wTest_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    //call .exe application and wait for output
    if (worker.CancellationPending)
    {   
        e.Cancel = true;
    }
}
```

Then, when you want to cancel the work, you should call this on your `BackgroundWorker`:

```
backgroundWorker.CancelAsync();
```

However, as you are *not* using the `BackgroundWorker` as it was meant to be used, I don't think that this will work for you. If you are waiting for the third party application to start, then you won't be able to set the `e.Cancel` property to `true`.

To be honest, I can't quite understand why you would use a `BackgroundWorker` just to start a process anyway. The `Process.Start` method takes no time to complete as it doesn't wait for any response. In my opinion, you'd be better off monitoring the [`Process.Exited` event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.exited%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and calling the [`Process.Kill` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.kill%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is have your `DoWork` delegate check for `e.Cancel` (in `DoWorkEventArgs`) property bring set to `true`. If `DoWork` is blocking, like waiting for `StandardOutput`, then that simply wont be possible.

Another approach would be to pass `Process.WaitForExit` an `int` stating how long it should wait for output:

```
process.WaitForExit(60000);
```